# How to make all cohort weeks start from 100% mark in Line charts using Tableau?

Tags: visualization, linechart, tableau-desktop

I'm trying to build a weekly cohort analysis depicted by line charts in Tableau. The problem is that all weeks line should start from 100%.

Below is the process I took :

dropping order date to columns and selecting week number
COUNTD (order id) and in rows
creating a calculated field : first purchase date`{ FIXED [User Id]:MIN([Order Date])}` and then
Dropping first purchase date to color field

I'm getting weeks depicted as lines (different colors) but can't figure out a way to make all lines starting from 100% point.

Here is the screenshot of what it should look like https://prnt.sc/1uugad5

Link to the dummy data where order_id is unique [Dummy Data link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12y8_fmiT9zcGc5x3whIe1-I8PefMiZLP/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=104686423957654811582&rtpof=true&sd=true) . Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the viz, I used COUNTD([User ID]) instead of order ID.

The x axis represent the difference of weeks between the order date and the cohort date.
Finally, the percent can be found using percent of total quick table calculation and using table across.